# Investigating 32 bit MESA driver selection

Tags: linux, 32bit-64bit, mesa

I've used NVidia card, with the properary drivers installed on a Debian Stretch.

But because i'm carry my hard drive between different machines (intel, amd, but always on amd64 act), i'm decided to drop the NVidia card, and rollback opengl to MESA in order to use 3D acceleration on every machine. After a lot of struggling i'm successfully identified and recovered some badly overwritten file (libGL.so, libdrm2.so, by NVidia installer).

Now i'm successfully recovered the 64bit related libraries, so glxgears, browser's WebGL support, gnuplot, etc. works well.

But 32bit libraries (wine, steam) still doesn't work well, it's always falls back to "Mesa X11" render.

I'v used glxgears
    `$ LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose glxinfo | grep "OpenGL renderer string"`
to identify which so and DRI selected. It's prints the lookup process and the renderer:

> ```
> libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/tls/r600_dri.so
> libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/r600_dri.so
> libGL: Using DRI2 for screen 0
> OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on AMD SUMO (DRM 2.50.0 / 4.12.0-0.bpo.1-amd64, LLVM 3.9.1)
> ```

To investigate in 32 bit libraries (we can't have from mesa both the 64 and 32 bit installed), i've downloaded the 32bit version:

```
$ apt-get download mesa-utils:i386
```

Unpacked it and tries to figure out why it's fails to select the proper DRI:

> ```
> LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose  ./glxinfo | grep "OpenGL renderer string"
> OpenGL renderer string: Mesa X11
> ```

The pevious 64bit glxinfo prints debugging information to the stderr therefore we can see how the selection happens.

With 32bit version i can't get any useful information, even if i specify the
    `LIBGL_DRIVERS_PATH=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/`
evironment variable, where mesa might find the proper 32 bit so.

> ```
> $ file /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/r600_dri.so
> /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/r600_dri.so: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=d5177f823f11ac8ea7412e517aa6684154de506e, stripped
> ```

How can i get more information about the MESA DRI selection?